# Error invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: django, django-views

I have the following optional filter:

```
cat_id = self.request.GET.get('cat_id', '')
return Product.objects.filter(category__pk=cat_id)
```

When optional cat_id is not passed I get this error:

```
ValueError at /api/products/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

My question is, how do I make it so that when cat_id is not passed the filter is something like this...

```
return Product.objects.filter()
```

**or can someone show me a better way, what if I had 10 optional filters to include?**

Comment: `if cat_id is not None` or something similar?

Comment: but it will still be in the filter part Product.objects.filter() and what if I had 10 different filters? I don't want 10 if not statements. people must have this situation all the time, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
filters = {}

cat_id = self.request.GET.get('cat_id', None)

if cat_id:
    filters["category__pk"] = cat_id

return Product.objects.filter(**filters)
```

edit: if I had quite a few arguments going to filter, I'd try and do something like this (untested):

```
# with all your possible lookups here
possible_filters = {"cat_id": "category__pk", "colour": "colour__pk", }

# and then go through the provided fields, and toggle the filters accordingly
enabled_filters = { possible_filters[filter]: self.request.GET[filter] for filter
                    in possible_filters
                    if self.request.GET.get(filter, None) }

return Product.objects.filter(**enabled_filters)
```

Comment: that's perfect. Is this how you would do this yourself?

Comment: Yeah, it works nicely. I've added another snippet for dealing with many lookup parameters.